# getting wrong fragment onclick of bottomnavigation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

Hi i'm making an app where i'm using fragments with bottom navigation however when i click on home button it doesnt load home fragment instead it loads the second fragment and moreover when i start the app home fragment doesnt load by default i know it may sound naive but i'm having this problem plaese if someone may guide me
my code for fragment navigation

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   FrameLayout frameLayout;
   FragmentManager fragmentManager;
   Fragment fragment;
   BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //BottomNavigationView b=findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);


        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

       if(findViewById(R.id.frame_container)!=null){
            if(savedInstanceState!=null){

                return;
            }
            /*HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, homeFragment,null);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
      /* Comment this line and it should work!*/
            //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            //transaction.commit();
        }
        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);

        //final SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sb);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        loadFragment(fragment);

                    case R.id.navigation_feed:
                        fragment = new FeedFragment();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_event:
                        fragment = new EventsFragment();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_nearby:
                        fragment = new NearbyFragment();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_profile:
                        fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;

            }
        });

    }

    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
       // HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment,null);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
      /* Comment this line and it should work!*/
        //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
        // load fragment
        //HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just forgot to **`return true;`** inside **`case R.id.navigation_home:`** check it

Try this

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_feed:
                        fragment = new FeedFragment();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_event:
                        fragment = new EventsFragment();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_nearby:
                        fragment = new NearbyFragment();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_profile:
                        fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;

            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi @Nilesh Home Fragment loads now but how can i make it as a default one when the app starts

Comment: @Smith just load your `Home Fragment` inside `oncraeate` method

Comment: Thanks @NIlesh i uncommented the code for home fragment in oncreate

Comment: and @Nilesh the card design layout you gave me yesterday when i add image that is bigger the card changes its shape but but text doesnt move so how can i make image to doesnt change the cards shape when it loads

Comment: @Smith please text me personly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169635/discussion-between-smith-and-nilesh-rathod).

Comment: sorry forgot to do that @NIlesh